# The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "swappedout". Protocols must match

Tags: security, google-chrome

I'm getting this strange error in the console on a locally hosted website (hosted in IIS).  The browser is Google Chrome.  Does anyone have a clue as to what's going on here and how to get rid of this error?

Cheers,

EDIT: restarting Google Chrome has made the error go away... would be nice to know why it was there in the first place though, it looks very odd...

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error while displaying some html data sent by my server inside iframe. The reason of error was presence of meta tag x-frame-options=deny in the html that stopped it from displaying in iframe.